# Filter not looking correct in Detail Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoGrid that has a Detail grid in it and its not looking like a filter that I have in another grid, but its the same code...
The DetailGrid filter looks like this...
[image: DetailGrid]

Notice the filters? well I am trying to get the Filter to look like my other grid's filter

[image: OtherGrid]

Here is the code that both grids are using...

```
    columns: [
        { field: "OptionID", title: "Option ID", hidden: true },
        {
            field: "OptionName", title: "Option Name", filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        { field: "OptionDescription", title: "Description" },
        { field: "OptionPriceComment", title: "Price" }
    ]
```

I made the assumption that since the filter was looking correctly in the other grid that doing the same thing would work in the detail grid.. Any idea's why this isn't looking the way it should?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work, but you have show only column configuration, but you will need to configure filterable Grid option.

```
 filterable: {
          mode: "row"
        },
```

I did an [working example](http://dojo.telerik.com/irELu) when you can compare and see some 
inconsistencies.

Hope this help